# How to handle closures in TypeScript (Angular injections)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, closures

I have an Angular factory service in JavaScript that I defined like this:

```
app.service('MyServiceFactory', ['$http', '$timeout', '$interval',
  function($http, $timeout, $interval) {

  function MyService() {
    // I can use all injected values here without additional efforts
  }

  this.Create = function() {
    return new MyService();
  }

}]);
```

Now I want to convert it into TypeScript:

```
module Services {

  export class MyServiceFactory {
    static $inject: string[] = ['$timeout', '$interval', '$http'];

    constructor(
      private timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
      private interval: angular.IIntervalService,
      private http: angular.IHttpService) {
    }
    public create(): MyService { return new MyService(); };
  }

  export class MyService() {
    // I have a problem here. I need to redefine and
    // initialize all variables, injected into my factory class
  }

  angular.module('MyModule').service('MyServiceFactory', MyServiceFactory);
}
```

Do you see what I mean? TypeScript does not allow nested classes, which could have solved the issue. Also TypeScript solution looks very uncool. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
export class MyService() {
    // I have a problem here. I need to redefine and
    // initialize all variables, injected into my factory class
  }
```

You can put the `Create` on `MyServiceFactory` i.e.:

```
module Services {

  export class MyServiceFactory {
    static $inject: string[] = ['$timeout', '$interval', '$http'];

    constructor(
      private timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
      private interval: angular.IIntervalService,
      private http: angular.IHttpService) {
    }
    public create(){ 
      // Use the revealing module pattern 
      // And let the compiler infer the return type
      // e.g.
      var foo = 23;
      return {
         foo
      }
    };
  }

  angular.module('MyModule').service('MyServiceFactory', MyServiceFactory);
}
```

Please note that valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the injected variables as parameters to your other class, e.g:

```
export class MyServiceFactory {
  static $inject: string[] = ['$timeout', '$interval', '$http'];

  constructor(
    private timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
    private interval: angular.IIntervalService,
    private http: angular.IHttpService) {

  }

  public create(): MyService {
    return new MyService(this.timeout, this.interval, this.http);
  }
}

export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
    private interval: angular.IIntervalService,
    private http: angular.IHttpService) {
    // no more problems here, you can play with the injected variables again
  }
}

angular.module('MyModule').service('MyServiceFactory', MyServiceFactory);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid. See how TypeScript code is almost three times large than my initial JavaScript solution?

Comment: Note that you don't need another class to return inside `create`. You can always use create to return the object you want, or you can even create a method in your class to return what you want.

Comment: In fact, you could even use your current Javascript approach and only implement the typings, you don't need to use ES6 classes at all. TypeScript is Javascript w/ typings, after all.